# Docker-compose up remove my existing conainer

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I just get a strange behavior when I run ‘docker-compose up -d’, it spin-up the container but it also remove one of my existing container.
This behavior does not happen at my other environment when I try to run the same docker-compose file.
Is the anyone have same experience and able to solve it ?
Any suggestion how to trace the root cause of this behavior ?

Thanks before.

Comment: it could happen if both containers have the same container_name, during docker-compose up docker could stop the previous container with matching name and start the current docker container.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what the structure of your project is, It would be better if you attached the `docker-compose.yml` file.
However when running docker-compose, if the containers name is the same, the previous container will be stopped and a container with the same name will be created again.
try the following method, this method may help you.
Have two or more separate `docker-compose.yml` files and execute each one you want as needed as follows.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose1.yml up -d
docker-compose -f docker-compose2.yml up -d
...
```